# Command not found with no command name

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

Since I installed [powerline-go](https://github.com/justjanne/powerline-go) on my fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, it throws `-bash: : command not found` error every time the prompt loads (after running a command, pressing enter, on startup, etc.).

Full output with `set -x`:

```bsh
 paul > ubuntu > ~ > $ > ​ <press enter>
++ _update_ps1
++++ jobs -p
++++ wc -l
+++ /home/paul/go/bin/powerline-go -error 0
++ PS1='​\[\e[38;5;250m\]\[\e[48;5;240m\] paul \[\e[48;5;238m\]\[\e[38;5;240m\]>\[\e[0m\]\[\e[38;5;250m\]\[\e[48;5;238m\] ubuntu \[\e[48;5;31m\]\[\e[38;5;238m\]>\[\e[0m\]\[\e[38;5;15m\]\[\e[48;5;31m\] ~ \[\e[48;5;236m\]\[\e[38;5;31m\]>\[\e[0m\]\[\e[38;5;15m\]\[\e[48;5;236m\] \$ \[\e[0m\]\[\e[38;5;236m\]>\[\e[0m\] ​'                                                               ++ ​​
-bash: ​​: command not found
 paul > ubuntu > ~ > $ > ​
```

I added this snippet to my `.bashrc`:

```bsh
function _update_ps1() {
    PS1="$($GOPATH/bin/powerline-go -error $?)"
}
if [ "$TERM" != "linux" ]; then
    PROMPT_COMMAND="_update_ps1; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
fi
```

Otherwise, it works perfectly fine, except for printing this error.
I tried running shellcheck if there is a zero-width character and didn't found any.

I use powerline-go on my other computer (also Ubuntu 20.04) and it works completely fine

Comment: What do you mean by use the prompt?

Comment: @David when the prompt shows, be it after running any command or after just pressing an enter. (edited the question accordingly)

Comment: Two things I would check: (1) a earlier definition of `PROMPT_COMMAND` with a value such as literal space like `PROMPT_COMMAND=\ ` or non-printing character; and (2) Windows-style line (CRLF) endings in your .bashrc file

Comment: So even after changing to `PROMPT_COMMAND="_update_ps1"` so the previous value doesn't matter and thoroughly checking line ending, it is still not working. :(